# VSTS Build Definition : adding multiple feeds in Nuget restore task

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am in the process of setting up a VSTS build definition. The build definition is simple. Steps :

1. get the source from VSTS Git repo's master branch
2. restore nuget packages
3. run msbuild

Step 2 is setup as following :

[image]

When I use "Feed(s) I select here", it only allows me to select one feed. Is this a bug ? Or the only way to use multiple feeds is through Nuget.config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it can only select one feed for Feed(s) I select here option in NuGet restore task.

And I created an issue [Enable to select multiple feeds in NuGet restore task Feed(s) I select here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6561) for this feature, you can follow up.

The workarounds for now is using the `NuGet.config` file which contains the feeds you need to use. Or add the VSTS feeds you need to use as endpoints, and then select these feed from **Credentials for feeds outside this account/collection** option.

Answer (score 8):

As another work around, one could also choose to create a **downstream** feed that is only an aggregate of the **upstream** feeds and use the aggregate feed name in the build.

With this approach, it may be prudent to remove any non-admin users from having access to this feed to prevent packages being added to it directly.

#### Illustrations:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I just hit this with my `yml` pipelines and spent an hour looking at the docs. So I thought on writing an answer here since things changed so much since then.

The way to go is still to use a `NuGet.config` file. But that's not enough. You also need to properly configure the `NuGetCommand@2` or `DotNetCoreCLI@2` in order for it to use the `.config` file. This is the way you configure it:

- **NuGetCommand@2**

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restoring NuGet packages'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.Config
```

- **DotNetCoreCLI@2**

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restoring NuGet packages
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.Config # Relative to root of the repository
```

You need specifically the `feedsToUse` property to have the value of `config`. Without it, the pipeline will not use your `.config` file.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget), you have two options:

- *use NuGet.org and/or **one Package Management feed** in the same account/collection as the build* (this is the option you chose in your example)

OR

- to use feeds specified in a NuGet.config file you've checked into source control (if you switch the radio button to "Feeds in my nuget.config")